# Custom XML formatter for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to define a new XML formatter in an Eclipse plugin? I have some XML files that must follow specific formatting rules, but see how way of plugging in to the formatter engine.

I can tie this formatter to files that are part of a project with a specific facet.

---

For context, I am maintaining the [Sling IDE Tooling for Eclipse](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/ide-tooling.html), and part of that application is concerned with synchronising local state with a remote JCR repository.

The synchronisation is based on XML files and folders stored on disk, following a well defined format - [FileVault DocView](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault/docview.html). These XML files can contain metadata attached to files and folders, but also arbitrary hierarchical data.

The CLI tool that is used as an alternative to the IDE tooling and almost always in production follows strict set of rules regarding indentation, XML attribute ordering, etc and also rewrites files when pushing them to the repository.

I would like to follow this model and allow the users of the IDE to format the XML files following the exact same preset. The formatting model is actually quite simple, shown below:

```java
format = new OutputFormat("xml", "UTF-8", true);
format.setIndent(4);
format.setLineWidth(0);
format.setBreakEachAttribute(true);
format.setSortAttributeNamesBy(AttributeNameComparator.INSTANCE);
```

The name comparator is also quite simple, sorting `xmlns` instructions first, then the namespaced properties, and then the other properties.

Comment: Please show the code you have so far and tell us exactly where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

This was requested in https://bugs.eclipse.org/460055 , but not implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I understand that there is now way to hook in 'Format' command? One alternative I'm considering is to contribute a custom action in the resource navigator context menu, not sure if there are others.

Comment: Correct, there is no framework to make this possible. ADT chose to work around it like a bug rather than request a cleaner way to do the same.

Comment: @RobertMunteanu Consider implementing and contributing what you need. This might be helpful for others as well. Hint: Eclipse (WTP) is open source and [nitind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27905/nitind) is the Eclipse WTP project lead.

Comment: Before it gets to that point, it would be worth exploring if the existing formatter can be improved to solve the problem--does it just need more preferences, when and why should a facet change how a file is formatted anyway, etc., or actually coding the intended formatting (creating the nondestructive TextEdits and applying them) so that it exists in some usable form that can be used to test and make sure such a framework actually meets the requirements.

Comment: @howlger ( and nitind ) - I've edited the question to contain more context. For the record, I don't really want to maintain a formatter, no matter how simple. If I can ensure that the desired formatter rules are _always_ applied to projects with a certain facet I'm happy.

Comment: @RobertMunteanu Please describe the problem. Do you want have the formatter inside the XML editor. If yes, a specific XML editor (WTP, lsp4xml, etc.)? Should the formatter triggered automatically (as save/clean-up action, via project builder, ...) or manually by the user? Does an implementation of the formatter already exist (also used by the CLI tool)? How is the information given in your last comment related to your question (for me, maintaining and contributing are alternatives, not synonyms)?

Comment: @howlger - WTP, manual trigger, implementation already exists. I have not looked into lsp4xml, not sure if it's a viable solution for us. Regarding maintaining/contributing - my point is that I don't necessarily want to write the code for it. If something exists in "the platform" that can do the job, I'd be happy to take advantage of it.

Comment: Formatting adjusts whitespace gaps, so wouldn't completely cover what's being asked about. There is a separate Cleanup functionality that is meant to rewrite actual content; that would be the place to have configurable attribute name sorting. What is meant by "`xmlns` instructions"?